# Component Move file is causing java.io.IOException, and is trying to move to a wrong folder

Tags: file, mule, mule-studio, mule-esb, mule4

I have a `Move file` component in my flow:

```
<sub-flow name="MoveFileToErrorDirectorySubFlow" doc:id="51f387ca-5faa-4ba4-af87-008a1698e104" >
    <file:move doc:name="MoveFileToErrorDir" doc:id="c99d732d-2fc5-4512-b50d-c97c9b4e8aff" sourcePath="${invoices.import.path}" targetPath="${invoices.error.path}" config-ref="XMLFile"/>
</sub-flow>
```

`invoices.import.path` is pointing to `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice`

`invoices.error.path` **should be** pointing to `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error`

But when I am trying to run the flow by pasting a file into `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/`

I get an error:

> Message               : An error occurred while executing 'move' operation on file '/home/user/invoices/import/invoice' to '/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error/invoice': Cannot move directory: /home/user/invoices/import/invoice to a subdirectory of itself: /home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error/invoice

First thing, why I am getting an error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot move directory: /home/user/invoices/import/invoice to a subdirectory of itself: /home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error/invoice

Second thing, why the target directory is `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error/invoice` instead of `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error`

Third thing, i am trying to move a **file** but it seems that it is trying to move a whole directory - to a wrong path as mentioned above...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to move a directory (`/home/user/invoices/import/invoice`) instead of a file inside that directory (let say `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/report.csv` as an example). The connector expects `sourcePath` path to be the path to the file, including the file name. The extension is part of the name by the way so don't miss it.

On the other hand, `targetPath` is expected to be a directory.

That explains all the issues.

1. Your sourcePath points to a directory. You can not move a directory into one of its own subdirectories. That doesn't make sense in any file systems I know of.
2. Because it is trying to move `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice` into `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error`, the resulting target would be to create an `invoice` sub directory of the `error` subdirectory, or `/home/user/invoices/import/invoice/error/invoice`.